# Getting error unnest is not a recognized built-in function name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I'm running a query using 'unnest' statement getting error unnest is not a recognized built-in function name. Is unnest is builtin sql function name? is so it's compatible versions are ?

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server does not support `unnest()`.

Comment: Where do you find this `UNNEST()` function???  I've never heard of it.

Comment: UNNEST is not a SQL Server function. It is in Postgress and (I think) IBM DB2... but not SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support arrays either so not sure how you were planning to use this if it did exist

Comment: @ellickakudy rajesh, can you please also post the query here. Community can help rewrite your query as equivalent in sql server